# Writing the minimum code to pass a unit test - without cheating!

Tags: unit-testing, tdd

When doing TDD and writing a unit test, how does one resist the urge to "cheat" when writing the first iteration of "implementation" code that you're testing?

For example:
Let's I need to calculate the Factorial of a number.  I start with a unit test (using MSTest) something like:

```
[TestClass]
public class CalculateFactorialTests
{
    [TestMethod]
    public void CalculateFactorial_5_input_returns_120()
    {
        // Arrange
        var myMath = new MyMath();
        // Act
        long output = myMath.CalculateFactorial(5);
        // Assert
        Assert.AreEqual(120, output);
    }
}
```

I run this code, and it fails since the `CalculateFactorial` method doesn't even exist.  So, I now write the first iteration of the code to implement the method under test, writing the [minimum](http://site.typemock.com/general-unit-testing-page/2009/9/11/test-driven-development-tdd.html?qs=Test_Driven_Development_TDD.php) [code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Test-driven_development#3._Write_some_code) required to pass the test.

The thing is, I'm continually tempted to write the following:

```
public class MyMath
{
    public long CalculateFactorial(long input)
    {
        return 120;
    }
}
```

This is, technically, correct in that it *really* is the minimum code required to *make that specific test pass* (go green), although it's clearly a "cheat" since it really doesn't even *attempt* to perform the function of calculating a factorial.  Of course, now the refactoring part becomes an exercise in "writing the correct functionality" rather than a true refactoring of the implementation.  Obviously, adding additional tests with different parameters will fail and force a refactoring, but you have to start with that one test.

So, my question is, how do you get that balance between "writing the minimum code to pass the test" whilst still keeping it functional and in the spirit of what you're actually trying to achieve?

Comment: It's a human thing: you have to resist the urge to cheat. There is nothing more to it. You could add more tests and write  more test code than code to test, but if you don't have that luxury than you'll need to just resist. There are MANY places in coding where we have to resist the urge to hack or cheat, because we know that, while it might work today, it won't work later.

Comment: Surely, in TDD, doing it the other way around is cheating - i.e. return 120 is the proper way.  I find it quite hard to make myself do that, and not race ahead and start writing the factorial calculation.

Comment: I would consider this a cheat, only because it may pass the test but it does not add any true functionality or get you closer to a final solution to the problem at hand.

Comment: If it turns out that client code code only ever passes in a 5, returning 120 is not just a non-cheat, but is actually a legitimate solution.

Comment: I agree with @PaulButcher - in fact, a lot of unit testing examples in texts and articles would take this approach.

Comment: Personally I'd write it with a check and a note: `if (input == 5) return 120; throw new ArgumentOutOfRange("TODO fix this");` or similar.  If the desire is to just make the icons green, how is that different than adding 'tests' that are `Assert.IsTrue(true)`.  However if its to mock up that function so you can work on other parts it is fully legit.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

It's perfectly legit.  Red, Green, Refactor.

The first test passes.

Add the second test, with a new input.

Now quickly get to green, you could add an if-else, which works fine.  It passes, but you are not done yet.

The third part of Red, Green, Refactor is the most important.  **Refactor to remove duplication**.  You WILL have duplication in your code now.  Two statements returning integers.  **And the only way to remove that duplication is to code the function correctly.**

I'm not saying don't write it correctly the first time.  I'm just saying it's not cheating if you don't.

Comment: The logical conclusion of that statement is that you can only have a single return statement in a method.  Are you certain that is a good idea?

Comment: This just raises the question, why not just write the function correctly in the first place?

Comment: @Robert, factorial numbers are trivially simple.  The real advantage of TDD is when you write non-trivial libraries, and writing the test first forces you to design the API before the implementation, which - in my experience - leads to better code.

Comment: @Thorbjørn: Of course.  But you're still thinking about solving a problem, not passing a test.

Comment: @Robert, it is you who are concerned about solving the problem instead of passing the test.  I am telling you that for non-trivial problems it simply works better to postpone the hard design until you have tests in place.

Comment: @Thorbjørn Ravn Andersen, no, I'm not saying you can only have one return.  There are valid reasons for multiple (ie, guard statements).  The issue is, both return statements were "equal".  They did the same 'thing'.  They just happened to have different values.  TDD isn't about rigidity, and adhering to a specific size of test/code ratio.  It's about creating a comfort level within your code base.  If you can write a failing test, then a function that will work for future tests of that function, great.  Do it, then write your edge case tests ensuring your function still works.

Comment: @Robert: Because if you are writing the function first, you are not doing TDD correctly, which is what this question is about.

Comment: @Chad, I think that "two return statements both returning an int" being duplicates is perhaps overdoing it a bit.  But again, depends on your style, and if it makes the code cleaner, fine with me.

Comment: @Thorbjørn Ravn Andersen, it's not that they both return ints, or that they are both return statements.  The issue is they both follow the same logic and return an answer.  But with two different code paths...that are identical aside from the constants used.  It's duplication of logic.

Comment: @Martin: You can write some tests first, if you like.  But I submit that if your development process doesn't result in an actual factorial function pretty quickly, there's a problem with your development process.

Comment: @Thorbjørn: With respect to factorials being simple, are you saying that the OP is *oversimplifying* with respect to his example?

Comment: @Robert, no, but the example is so small that it is too tempting to skip something because you can see what would most likely go in the final solution.  A better example would be "sort an array".

Comment: @Robert: _Clearly_ this is an example created by the OP to make his question easier to understand. Using this silly code example to prove a more generalized "TDD is bad" argument seems extremely pointless (not to mention of topic).

Comment: @All - Martin is correct in that I chose a "factorial" function simply to demonstrate the point and I believe it's a good example for that. FWIW, I don't think TDD is bad, in fact I love TDD, but I'm no TDD Expert and this question is related to something that I personally perceive to be a bit of a "cheat" by myself, although @Chad's answer about it not being a cheat since additional tests and subsequent refactoring will "evolve" the correct (in this case, factorial) function is alluringly pragmatic!

Comment: @Chad strongly disagree; see my answer

Comment: the point of not writing the full (albeit simple) implementation at once is that you then have no guarantee at all that your tests even CAN fail. the point of seeing a test fail before making it pass is that you then have actual proof that your change to the code is what satisfied the assertion you made on it. this is the single reason why TDD is so great for building a regression test suite and completely wipes the floor with the "test after"-approach in that sense.

Answer (score 26):

Clearly an understanding of the ultimate goal, and the achievement of an algorithm that meets that goal, is required.

TDD is not a magic bullet for design; you still have to know how to solve problems using code, and you still have to know how to do that at a level higher than a few lines of code to make a test pass.

I like the idea of TDD because it encourages good design; it makes you think about how you can write your code so that it is testable, and generally that philosophy will push the code towards a better design overall. But you still have to know how to architect a solution.

I do not favor reductionist TDD philosophies that claim you can grow an application by simply writing the smallest amount of code to pass a test.  Without thinking about architecture, *this won't work,* and your example proves that.

Uncle Bob Martin [says this:](https://web.archive.org/web/20160822000620/http://s3.amazonaws.com/hanselminutes/hanselminutes_0171.pdf)

> If you're not doing Test Driven
> Development, it's very difficult to
> call yourself a professional. Jim
> Coplin called me on the carpet for
> this one. He didn't like that I said
> that. In fact, his position right now
> is that Test Driven Development is
> destroying architectures because
> people are writing tests to the
> abandon of any other kind of thought
> and tearing their architectures apart
> in the mad rush to get tests to pass
> and he's got an interesting point,
> that's an interesting way to abuse the
> ritual and lose the intent behind the
> discipline.
>
> if you're not thinking through the
> architecture, if what you're doing
> instead is ignoring architecture and
> throwing tests together and getting
> them to pass, you're destroying the
> thing that will allow the building to
> stay up because it's the concentration
> on the structure of the system and
> solid design decisions that help the
> system maintain its structural
> integrity.
>
> You cannot simply just throw a whole
> bunch of tests together and make them
> pass for decade after decade after
> decade and assume that you're system
> is going to survive. We don't want to
> evolve ourselves into hell. So a good
> test driven developer is always
> conscious of making architectural
> decisions, always thinking of the big
> picture.

Comment: Not really an answer to the question, but 1+

Comment: @rmx: Um, the question is: *How do you get that balance between "writing the minimum code to pass the test" whilst still keeping it functional and in the spirit of what you're actually trying to achieve?*  Are we reading the same question?

Comment: The ideal solution is an algorithm and has nothing to do with architecture. Doing TDD won't make you invent algorithms. At some point you need to make steps in terms of an algorithm/solution.

Comment: I agree with @rmx.  This doesn't really answer my specific question, per se, but it does give rise to food for thought as to how TDD in general fits into the big picture of the overall software development process.  So, for that reason, +1.

Comment: I think you could substitute "algorithms" - and other terms - for "architecture" and the argument still holds; it's all about being unable to see the wood for the trees. Unless you are going to write a separate test for every single integer input, TDD will not be able to distinguish between a proper factorial implementation and some perverse hard-coding which works for all tested cases but not others. The problem with TDD is the ease with which "all tests pass" and "the code is good" are conflated. At some point a heavy measure of common sense needs to be applied.

Answer (score 19):

A very good question...and I have to disagree with almost everyone except @Robert.

Writing

```
return 120;
```

for a factorial function to make one test pass is a *waste of time*. It's not "cheating", nor is it following red-green-refactor literally. It is **wrong**.

Here's why:

- **Calculate Factorial** is the feature, not "return a constant". "return 120" is *not* a calculation.
- the 'refactor' arguments are misguided; if you have two test cases for 5 and 6, this code is still wrong, because you are not calculating a factorial *at all*:

  ```
  if (input == 5) { return 120; } //input=5 case
  else { return 720; }   //input=6 case
  ```
- if we follow the 'refactor' argument *literally*, then when we have 5 test cases we would invoke YAGNI and implement the function using a lookup table:

  ```
  if (factorialDictionary.Contains(input)) {
      return factorialDictionary[input]; 
  }
  throw new Exception("Input failure");
  ```

None of these are actually calculating anything, *you are*. And that's not the task!

Comment: I think the oposing argument was based on the BDD principle (which you seem to have missed) that unit tests encode requirements. Therefore if some code passes the tests, it meets requirements and is valid.

Comment: @rmx: nope, didn't miss it; "refactor to remove duplication" can be satisfied with a lookup table. BTW the principle that unit tests encode requirements is not specific to BDD, it is a general principle of Agile/XP. If the requirement was "Answer the question 'what is the factorial of 5'" then 'return 120;' would be legit ;-)

Comment: @Steven A.Lowe, you refactor to remove code smells.  Constants are code smells, hence, you would remove the constants, and you wouldn't replace them with a lookup table, because that lookup table is just another constant

Comment: @Chad all of which is unnecessary work - just write the function the first time ;-)

Comment: @Steven A.Lowe, by that logic, why write any tests?! "Just write the application the first time!"  The point of TDD, is small, safe, incremental changes.

Comment: @Chad: strawman.

Comment: @Steven A. Lowe. Pot, meet kettle.

Comment: @Chad sorry, I meant to say _reductio ad absurdum_, not strawman; my mistake

Comment: @Chad: think of it this way - if testing a factorial function with 5 --> 120 was the only test case, would you stick 'return 120;' into the code and ship the product? ;-)

Comment: @Steven A. Lowe. ...now who's making illogical arguments.

Comment: @Chad :-D sometimes features are underspecified ;-)

Comment: the point of not writing the full (albeit simple) implementation at once is that you then have no guarantee at all that your tests even CAN fail. the point of seeing a test fail before making it pass is that you then have actual proof that your change to the code is what satisfied the assertion you made on it. this is the single reason why TDD is so great for building a regression test suite and completely wipes the floor with the "test after"-approach in that sense. you never accidentally write a test that cannot fail. also, take a look at uncle bobs prime factor kata.

Comment: you can also read about this process here https://blog.8thlight.com/uncle-bob/2013/05/27/TheTransformationPriorityPremise.html

it's all about focusing on the requirements and letting the code grow naturally, always having full confidence that your tests both drive the design forward and will serve as regression tests in the future.

Comment: Let's assume you write a test 5!==120. You then write the full factorial algorithm. Since you seem to be focussing on not wasting time, it would be a waste of time to write any further tests (as well as pointless) because they would all start off green. So that means that you are relying on 5!==120 to ensure that the factorial is working properly. Someone could come along and rewrite your function to `return 120` and no tests would fail. Now substitute a more complicated function for the factorial. You can't expect a single test to cover all the behaviour nor to know everything in advance.

Comment: To see my tests fail, I return n! / 2. Returning a single constant number is just idiotic.

Answer (score 11):

When you've written only one unit test, the one-line implementation (`return 120;`) is legitimate.  Writing a loop calculating the value of 120 - **that would be cheating!**

Such simple initial tests are a good way to catch edge cases and prevent one-off errors.  Five actually isn't the input value I'd start with.

A rule of thumb that could be useful here is: **zero, one, many, lots**.  Zero and one are important edge cases for the factorial.  They can be implemented with one-liners.  The "many" test case (e.g. 5!) would then force you to write a loop.  The "lots" (1000!?) test case could force you to implement an alternative algorithm to handle very large numbers.

Comment: The "-1" case would be interesting. Because it's not well-defined, so both the guy writing the test and the guy writing the code have to agree first what _should_ happen.

Comment: +1 for actually pointing out that `factorial(5)` is a bad first test. we start from the simplest possible cases and in each iteration we make the tests a bit more specific, urging the code to become a bit more generic. this is what uncle bob calls the transformation priority premise (https://blog.8thlight.com/uncle-bob/2013/05/27/TheTransformationPriorityPremise.html)

Answer (score 5):

As long as you only have a single test, then the minimal code needed to pass the test is truly `return 120;`, and you can easily keep it for that as long as you don't have any more tests.

This allows you to postpone further design until you actually write the tests that exercise OTHER return values of this method.

Please remember that the test is the runnable version of your specification, and if all *that* specification says is that f(6)=120 then that fits the bill perfectly.

Comment: Seriously?  By this logic, you will have to rewrite the code every time someone comes up with a new input.

Comment: @Robert, at SOME point adding a new case will not result in the _simplest_ possible code anymore, at which point you write a new implementation.  As you have the tests in place already, you know exactly when your new implementation does the same as the old one.

Comment: @Thorbjørn Ravn Andersen, exactly, the most important part of Red-Green-Refactor, is the refactoring.

Comment: +1: This is the general idea from my knowledge as well, but something needs to be said about fulfilling the implied contract (ie. the method name _factorial_). If you only ever spec (ie test) f(6) = 120 then you only ever need to 'return 120'. Once you start adding tests to ensure that f(x) == x*x-1...*x-x-1 : upperBound >= x >= 0 then you will arrive at a function that satisfies the factorial equation.

Comment: Actually, the specification should say that it satisfies *all* inputs, not just F(6).

Comment: @SnOrfus, the place for "implied contracts" to be is in the test cases.  If you contract is for factorials, you _TEST_ if known factorials are and if known non-factorials aren't.  Plenty of them.  Doesn't take long to convert the list of the ten first factorials to a for-loop testing every number up to the tenth factorial.

Comment: @Robert, yes, and the test suite is the runnable version of the spec.

Comment: @Thorbjørn Ravn Andersen: Agreed, I rescind my comment about the implied contract.

Comment: @Robert Harvey: Not _all_ inputs. factorial(long.MaxValue) would throw.

Comment: @SnOrfus, or just silently overflow.  This would, however, be a very good test case for numerically sensitive implementations.

Answer (score 4):

If you are able to "cheat" in such a way, it suggests that your unit tests are flawed.

Rather than testing the factorial method with a single value, test it was a range of values. Data-driven testing can help here.

View your unit tests as a manifestation of the requirements - they must collectively define the behaviour of the method which they test. (This is known as [behaviour driven development](http://blog.dannorth.net/introducing-bdd/) - its the future `;-)`)

So ask yourself - if someone were to change the implementation to something incorrect, would your tests still pass or would they say "hang on a minute!"?

Bearing that in mind, if your only test was the one in your question, then technically, the corresponding implementation is correct. The problem is then viewed as poorly-defined requirements.

Comment: As nanda pointed out, you can always add an endless series of `case` statements to a `switch`, and you can't write a test for every possible input and output for the OP's example.

Comment: You could technically test values from `Int64.MinValue` to `Int64.MaxValue`. It would take a long time to run but it would explicitly define the requirement with no room for error. With the current technology, this is unfeasable (I suspect that it might become more common in the future) and I agree, you could cheat but I think the OPs question was not a practical one (no-one would actually cheat in such a way in practice), but a theoretical one.

Comment: @rmx: If you could do that, the *tests would be the algorithm,* and you would no longer need to write the algorithm.

Comment: It's true. My university thesis actually involves the automatic generation of the implementation using the unit-tests as a guide with a genetic algorithm as an aid to TDD - and it is only possible with solid tests. The difference is that binding your requirements to your code typically are far more difficult to read and grasp than a single method that embodies the unit-tests. Then comes the question: if your implementation is a manifestation of your unit tests, and your unit-tests are a manifestation of your requirements, why not just skip testing altogether? I dont have an answer.

Comment: Also, are'nt we, as humans, just as likely to make a mistake in unit-tests as we are in the implementation code? So why unit test at all?

Comment: @Robert, why would the test be the algorithm?

Comment: @Thorbjørn: The tests would essentially be a lookup table (albeit a very large one).

Comment: @Robert, please consider the case where you are testing a space restricted implementation _without_ the large lookup table, and you need to ensure that it works correctly.

Comment: @Thorbjørn: You can do *that* with Test-After Development.  TDD (as I understand it) is primarily about design, and secondarily about testing.

Comment: @Robert, I consider TDD to be Test-Driven-Development.  I encourage you to write a new library in this way.   I recently did one, and mailed the test suite to the customer programmer who was to use it.  It worked out _very_ well.

Comment: @rmx, because the chances of making the same mistake in both the test, and the implementation is lessened.  Think back to math class, you had to do your work, then write the proof.  `4 - x = 2`, therefor `-x = 2 - 4`, therefor `x = 4 - 2`, therefor `x = 2`, then you go back and substitute for x to prove it `4 - 2 = 2`, `2 = 2`.  Yes you *could* make a mistake in the proof (test) and implementation, but it's less likely.

Answer (score 3):

Just write more tests.  Eventually, it would be *shorter* to write

```
public long CalculateFactorial(long input)
{
    return input <= 1 ? 1 : CalculateFactorial(input-1)*input;
}
```

than

```
public long CalculateFactorial(long input)
{
    switch (input) {
       case 0: return 1;
       case 1: return 1;
       case 2: return 2;
       case 3: return 6;
       case 4: return 24;
       case 5: return 120;
    }
}
```

:-)

Comment: Wh not just write the algorithm correctly in the first place?

Comment: @Robert, it is *the* correct algorithm for calculating factorial of a number from 0 to 5.  Besides, what does "correctly" mean?  This is a very simple example, but when it goes more complex, there become many gradations of what "correct" means.  Is a program that requires root access "correct" enough?  Is using XML "correct", instead of using CSV?  You can't answer this.  Any algorithm is correct as long as it satisfies some business requirements, which are formulated as tests in TDD.

Comment: It should be noted that since the output type is long, there is only a small number of input values (20 or so) that the function can possibly handle correctly, therefore a large switch statement is not necessarily the worst implementation - if speed is more important than code size, the switch statement might be the way to go, depending on your priorities.

Answer (score 3):

Writing "cheat" tests is OK, for sufficiently small values of "OK".  But recall - unit testing is only complete when all tests pass *and no new tests can be written that will fail*.  If you really want to have a CalculateFactorial method that contains a bunch of **if** statements (or even better, a big **switch/case** statement :-) you can do that, and since you're dealing with a fixed-precision number the code required to implement this is finite (although probably rather large and ugly, and perhaps limited by compiler or system limitations on the maximum size of a procedure's code).  At this point if you *really* insist that all development has to be driven by a unit test you can write a test that requires the code to compute the result in an amount of time shorter than that which can be accomplished by following all the branches of the **if** statement.

Basically, TDD can help you write code **which implements requirements correctly**, but it can't force you to write **good** code.  That's up to you.

Share and enjoy.

Comment: +1 for "unit testing is only complete when all tests pass and no new tests can be written that will fail"  Many people are saying its legit to return the constant, but don't follow with "for the short term", or "if the overall requirements only need those specific cases"

Answer (score 1):

If you still able to cheat then the tests are not enough. Write more tests! For your example, I will try to add tests with input 1, -1, -1000, 0, 10, 200.

Nevertheless, if you're really commit to cheat you can write an endless if-then. In this case, nothing could help except code review. You would be soon caught on acceptance test (**written by other person!**)

The problem with unit tests is sometimes programmers look at them as unnecessary work. The correct way to see them is as tool for you to make the result of your work correct. So if you create an if-then, you know unconsciously that there are other cases to consider. This means you have to write another tests. And so on and so on until you realize the cheating is not working and it is better to just code the correct way. If you still feel that you are not finish, you are not finish.

Comment: So it sounds like you are saying that merely writing just enough code for the test to pass (as TDD advocates) is *not sufficient.* You also have to keep sound software design principles in mind.  I agree with you BTW.

Answer (score 1):

I do 100% agree with Robert Harveys suggestion here, it's not just about making tests pass, you need to keep the overall goal in mind too.

As a solution to your painpoint of "it's only verified to work with a given set of inputs" I'd propose using data driven tests, such as xunit theory. The power behind this concept is that it allows you to easily create Specifications of inputs to outputs.

For Factorials, a test would look like this:

```
    [Theory]
    [InlineData(0, 1)]
    [InlineData( 1, 1 )]
    [InlineData( 2, 2 )]
    [InlineData( 3, 6 )]
    [InlineData( 4, 24 )]
    public void Test_Factorial(int input, int expected)
    {
        int result = Factorial( input );
        Assert.Equal( result, expected);
    }
```

You could even implement a test-data provide (that returns `IEnumerable<Tuple<xxx>>`) and encode a mathematic invariant, such as repeatedly dividing by n will yield n-1).

I find this tp be a very powerful way of testing.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that your choice of test is not the best test.

I would start off with:

factorial(1) as the first test,

factorial(0) as the second

factorial(-ve) as the third

and then continue on with non-trivial cases

and finish up with an overflow case.

Comment: What is `-ve`??

Comment: a negative value.

Answer (score 0):

The fallacy here in this example is that the library method under test will contain something simple and well-known.  That the amount of work needed to write the correct production-ready method is about the same as the amount of work needed to just make the test pass.   For any non-trivial piece of code that is simply not true.

This is actually not true even for factorials because it takes longer to calculate them than to look them up in an array for example, but what if you don't have a pre-calculated value in your array?  Can you work with built-in native datatypes or do you need greater precision which requires using a custom data type?  Should it be able to handle fractional values when you need the gamma function?  What should happen if an invalid number is passed?

All these things would require you to *come back later*, and fix the initial implementation so what you consider the correct solution to implement at first glance, may not actually be the one required!  And it may take longer to implement than you expect, especially when you consider corner cases and production quality error handling.  And this is just for something as simple and well-defined as a factorial.

By hardcoding just the values needed by your current test suite, you can postpone all this work for later when you know the needs better, and work on actually getting the rest of tests for what you work on to run.

Comment: So you come back to it later, when you have completely forgotten how your code works. Excellent strategy. What about having it work for actual use cases?

Comment: @gnasher729 As you undoubtedly know already TDD is about designing your API up front before you have too much code involved to be able to easily change the API cut, so write as more test as you can before deciding on the implementaiton.   Also, if you "forget how your code works" you are most likely not writing and using your tests correctly.

Comment: @gnasher729 Perhaps I was not clear enough in expressing that this example is probably too simple to be non-representative of real code.

Answer (score 0):

There is a saying: We should keep an open mind, but not so open that our brain falls out.

Not writing a fully working factorial function is in the “your brain falls out” category. The argument “but but we need to check that wrong return values produce test failures” is nonsense - I do this by a two character change returning n! + 1. That has the advantage that I can test the tests in a meaningful way, in case we have a test “5! must be between 100 and 150”. And if you have created an implementation where returning n! + 1 is difficult then figure out why it is difficult and fix it.

Where it makes sense: You write something a bit more difficult. Like translating a string to title case. That’s where you can reasonably start with code that works with a single word of ASCII letters, then multiple or zero words, then things like “john’s” -> “John’s” and not “John’S” and so on. And in the last case for example, I’d expect you to not look for an apostrophe only in your code, but all kinds of characters that cause this behaviour.

Comment: So what you say, is that the example is too simple?